# Jython : Listing all threads within a JVM including its state

Tags: multithreading, jython

I'm trying to get a list of all the running threads and their status i.e. 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', LOCKED'.

I've got this initial piece of code:

```
from java.lang import Thread
list = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()
for key in list:
     print list
```

So, what I'm trying to do is list the threads including its status.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the thread state via [Thread#getState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29). E.g.,

```python
from java.lang import Thread
threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()
for thread in threads:
    print thread.getState()
```

The result from `getState()` will be a [Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html). I get the following when running this from the Jython shell:

```python
>>> from java.lang import Thread
>>> for thread in Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet():
...     print thread.getState()
...
WAITING
RUNNABLE
WAITING
RUNNABLE
```

Comment: Perfect! To get both the thread list and its state using your example I simply add: print thread, thread.getState() and its exactly what I need. Thank you very much!